# Disabled option not working properly on Android Tablet

Tags: html, css, angularjs, html-select, tablet

I am using select tag for mobile and tablet device.

On mobile device, it is working fine but on tablet, the select tag is not functioning properly.

My problem is : The option is getting disabled but the disabled options are not getting transparent(Faint in color).

Below is the code sample :

```
<select id="nativeDropDown" name='nativeDropDown' class="trend-filter native-dropdown-position" ng-click="openNativeDropDown()">
      <option value='selectOption' selected data-ng-show="isIphone"></option>
      <option value='lastDay' data-ng-disabled="chartType === 'boxplot'" data-bas-translate="LastDayFilter"></option>
      <option value='last7Days' data-ng-disabled="chartType === 'boxplot'" data-bas-translate="Last7DaysFilter"></option>
      <option value='last30Days' data-bas-translate="Last30DaysFilter"></option>
      <option value='last12Months' data-bas-translate="Last12MonthsFilter"></option>
      <option value='allTime' data-ng-disabled="!enableBoxplotForAllTime()" data-bas-translate="AllTime"></option>
      <option value='customRange' data-bas-translate="CustomRangeFilter"></option></select>

.trend-filter 
{
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    text-indent: 1px;
    text-overflow: '';
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 35px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    /*opacity: 0.5;*/
    width: 40px;
    margin-left: -40px;
}

.native-dropdown-position {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99999;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using javascript validation instead.
And use the following code:

```
document.getElementById("    ").disabled = true; //Fill the white spaces with whatever you name it
```

Comment: Thank you for commenting. Your solution is not working.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8objv405/4/ Check this fiddle and try opening it in desktop,tablet(android) and mobile and check the difference. I guess, it's a bug in native select in case of android tablet.